# R use an if/else statement to make a new column populated with conditional values

Tags: r, if-statement

Our dataset:

```
mydat <- data.frame(
  Date=c("Jan 1, 2022", "Jan 1, 2022", "Jan 2, 2022","Jan 4, 2022", "Jan 4, 2022", "Jan 6, 2022"),
  City=c("Worcester","Boston","Ashburn","Brockton","Cambridge", "Springfield"),
  Users=c(3,34,1,2,1,2))
```

Which looks like this:

| Date | City | Users |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Jan 1, 2022 | Worcester | 3 |
| Jan 1, 2022 | Boston | 34 |
| Jan 2, 2022 | Ashburn | 1 |
| Jan 4, 2022 | Brockton | 2 |
| Jan 4, 2022 | Cambridge | 1 |
| Jan 6, 2022 | Springfield | 2 |

I want to make a new column that has the values for a certain city, and blank for all the ones not in that city.

I tried to do this with an if/else like this:

`mydat$boston_users <- if (dat$City == "Boston") mydat$Users else " "`

What ends up happening is I get blanks in the new column, which looks like this:

| Date | City | Users | boston_users |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Jan 1, 2022 | Worcester | 3 |  |
| Jan 1, 2022 | Boston | 34 |  |
| Jan 2, 2022 | Ashburn | 1 |  |
| Jan 4, 2022 | Brockton | 2 |  |
| Jan 4, 2022 | Cambridge | 1 |  |
| Jan 6, 2022 | Springfield | 2 |  |

So I say well my statement must be broken, so when I put in something absurd that I KNOW won't be there, I am able to get the values to populate.

`mydat$hello_users <- if ("hello" == "hello") mydat$Users else " "`

| Date | City | Users | hello_users | boston_users |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Jan 1, 2022 | Worcester | 3 | 3 |  |
| Jan 1, 2022 | Boston | 34 | 34 |  |
| Jan 2, 2022 | Ashburn | 1 | 1 |  |
| Jan 4, 2022 | Brockton | 2 | 2 |  |
| Jan 4, 2022 | Cambridge | 1 | 1 |  |
| Jan 6, 2022 | Springfield | 2 | 2 |  |

I know this is really simple but I'm missing it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out

`dat$BostonUsers <- ifelse(dat$City == "Boston", dat$Users, " ")`

This creates a new column with the values from the previous column and the rest appear as blank. My issue before was that I was trying to make a function rather than just the ifelse feasure in R

Answer (score 0):

I use NA instead of blank " " because otherwise it will change the data type to string.
You can put a list of cities in `c("your_city")` i.e. `c("Boston", "NY", "York)`

`mydat$boston_users <- ifelse(dat$City %in% c("<Your_city>"), mydat$Users, NA)`

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't work. I gave a very short sample list but the # of cities is far too great to list out like c(x,y,z). Also, when I tried putting "NA" as the else in my existing function, everything, including the city "Boston" filled with NA, much like my "Hello" example

Comment: Please share the function you're using. Also the c(x,y,z) is supposed to be the city you want to fill data, as you write in the question the new column "has the values for a certain city",